# Undefined background when scrolling horizontally to show element oveflown view port width

Tags: html, css

I have a two column layout (left bar and main content container) having another bar on the top of page. Background of the main container has vertical gradient. It works as expected when I resize browser's window.

If there is an non-wrappable element overflowing view port width, browser shows horizontal scroll bar. But if the content is scrolled right, on the right of page's body, there is undefined - white background.

I tried to simplified my layout and prepared SSCCE example in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ltoezupp/75/)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  background: white;
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 0.85em;
  overflow: scroll;
}

#topbar {
  background-color: #C0C0F0;   /* SSCCE */
  height: 48px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

#loginbar {
  margin-top: 12px;
  float: right;
  width: 166px;
  height: 32px;
  padding-right: 10px;  /* SSCCE */
  text-align: right;  /* SSCCE */
}

#leftbar {
  background-color: #C0F0C0;  /* SSCCE */
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  min-height: 90vh;
}

#container {
  margin-left: 150px;
  background-color: #DCDCDC;
  min-height: 90vh;
}

div.ContentWithGradientViewPort {
  padding-left: 16px;
  padding-top: 8px;
  min-height: 90vh;
  background: linear-gradient(#E0E0E0, #A3A3A3);
}

div.TopFilterBar {
  background-color: #DCDCA0;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

<body>
  <!-- Common layout -->
  <div>
    <div id="topbar">
    <!-- SSCCE --><div id="loginbar">XXX</div>
    </div>
    <div id="leftbar">
      <!-- SSCCE --><div style="padding:10px">XXX</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="container">

    <!-- content rendered by specific page  -->
    <div class="TopFilterBar">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="ContentWithGradientViewPort">
      <!-- SSCCE, width great than view port width -->
      <table width=700px>
        <tr>
          <td style="background-color:yellow">
            An overflown content
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

Please, is there a way how expand background with gradient to full browsers window width? Even with different DOM structure?

Thanks, pf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to apply `overflow:scroll` to your `div.ContentWithGradientViewPort` element.

This should fix it all up for you :)

Comment: Thanx, Will. It really did :)

Answer (score 0):

change   `<table width=700px>` to `<table width>` this is causing you issue of preventing the table expand to fill the content.

see

```css
body {
  margin: auto;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  background: blue;
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 0.85em;
  overflow: scroll;
}


#topbar {
  background-color: #C0C0F0;   /* SSCCE */
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  height: 48px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

#loginbar {
  margin-top: 12px;
  float: right;
  width: 166px;
  height: 32px;
  padding-right: 10px;  /* SSCCE */
  text-align: right;  /* SSCCE */
}

#leftbar {
  background-color: #C0F0C0;  /* SSCCE */
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  min-height: 90vh;
}

#container {
  margin-left: 150px;
  background-color: #DCDCDC;
  min-height: 90vh;
}

div.ContentWithGradientViewPort {
  padding-left: 16px;
  padding-top: 8px;
  background: linear-gradient(#E0E0E0, #A3A3A3);
}

div.TopFilterBar {
  background-color: #DCDCA0;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

<body>
  <!-- Common layout -->
  <div id="main">
    <div id="topbar">
    <!-- SSCCE --><div id="loginbar">XXX</div>
    </div>
    <div id="leftbar">
      <!-- SSCCE --><div style="padding:10px">XXX</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="container">

    <!-- content rendered by specific page  -->
    <div class="TopFilterBar">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="ContentWithGradientViewPort">
      <!-- SSCCE, width great than view port width -->
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td style="background-color:yellow">
            An overflown content
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: No, it does not. Is just simulates overflown content for SSCCE purpose (in reality it is complex jQuery dataTable)